# redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream

Tags: redis, jedis

I am trying to add some data to a Redis server while using a Jedis client and I am getting the following error: `Unexpected end of stream` error. What could be the reasons for this to happen?

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.
>
> [info]   at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:198)
>
> [info]   at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
>
> [info]   at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:128)
>
> [info]   at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:192)
>
> [info]   at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:282)
>
> [info]   at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:181)
>
> [info]   at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.watch(Jedis.java:1449)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same exception. In my case the problem was two concurrent threads trying to use Jedis at the same time. Once I made sure that only single thread writes/reads to/from my Jedis client, the problem went away.

Comment: Yes, for me also it was the same problem. Resolved this by assuring that only single thread write/read. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, how did you assure this?

Answer (score 0):

redis server has set the timeout

```
config get timeout
```

jedisPoolConfig setting setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis is not reasonable

Answer (score 0):

The embedded Redis server takes a while to release the port. Adding a 10 seconds sleep at the end of the afterAll methods works for me. I agree it is not a clean solution.

```
override def afterAll() {
    super.afterAll()
    jedis.close()
    redisCluster.stop()
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10)
}
```